# How to build an EAR project with EJB and WAR using Maven?

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, ear

I tried to create EAR Project with EJB and WAR but I have some problem.
I created the main project from the [Java EE 6 EAR Archetype](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes/ear-javaee6):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes</groupId>
    <artifactId>ear-javaee6</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I created the EJB module from the [Java EE 6 EJB JAR Archetype](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes/ejb-javaee6):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo.archetypes</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb-javaee6</artifactId>
    <version>1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

And then I created the second module from the [Javax Faces WAR Archetype](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/javax.faces-war-archetype):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces-war-archetype</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Then I added dependencies to main pom.xml:

```
<!-- Define the versions of your ear components here -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>QCforCC-main</groupId>
        <artifactId>QCforCC-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>ejb</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>QCforCC-main</groupId>
        <artifactId>QCforCC-war</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <type>war</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And then I tried to build the project - using maven clean and instal .
But I have an error:

```
  [ERROR] The projects in the reactor contain a cyclic reference: Edge between 'Vertex{label='QCforCC-main:QCforCC-war:1.0-SNAPSHOT'}' and 'Vertex{label='QCforCC-main:QCforCC-ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT'}' introduces to cycle in the graph QCforCC-main:QCforCC-ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT --> QCforCC-main:QCforCC-war:1.0-SNAPSHOT --> QCforCC-main:QCforCC-ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT -      [Help 1] 
  [ERROR]
  [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch. 
  [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. 
  [ERROR]  
  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
  [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectCycleException

  Process finished with exit code 1
```

And in EAR `pom.xml` I have:

```
<modules>
    <module>QCforCC-ejb</module>
    <module>QCforCC-war</module>
</modules>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
```

But if I change `<packaging>pom</packaging>` to `<packaging>ear</packaging>`
IDEA show error in popup:

```
  Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs: 
  [WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.(groupId:artifactId)' must be unique but found duplicate declaration of plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-ear-plugin @ line 41, column 21 
  [ERROR]   'packaging' with value 'ear' is invalid. Aggregator projects require 'pom' as packaging. @ line 12, column 16
```

Answer (score 15):

I highly suggest that you understand how multi-module builds work. The Sonatype book has a great [chapter](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) describing in great detail.

To build an EAR with an EJB and a WAR, you actually need *three* modules, for the EJB, WAR and EAR. The parent POM just holds everything together and has a packaging type of POM.

So the parent pom.xml should look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
    <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>Multi Chapter Simple Parent Project</name>

    <modules>
        <module>ejb-module</module>
        <module>war-module</module>
        <module>ear-module</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Then, each of the child POMs would look like this:

ejb-module/pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ejb-module</artifactId>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
</project>
```

war-module/pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>war-module</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>simple-webapp Maven Webapp</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

ear-module/pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                         http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
        <artifactId>simple-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>ear-module</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    <name>EAR module</name>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbModule>
                        <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ejb-module</artifactId>
                        <bundleFilename>ejb-module.jar</bundleFilename>
                    </ejbModule>
                    <webModule>
                        <groupId>org.sonatype.mavenbook.multi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>war-module</artifactId>
                        <contextRoot>/foo</contextRoot>
                    </webModule>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: what is <ejbModule> and <webModule>?

Comment: Refer to the documentation for the maven-ear-plugin here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-ear-plugin/modules.html

Comment: Artifact QCforCC-ear:ejb exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Archive type of C:\app\QCforCC-mainApp\QCforCC-ear\target\QCforCC-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT was not recognized

Comment: Edit your question with the updated POM files, the command you ran and the build output.

Comment: Think the ejbModule and webModule should be inside an element `<modules>`

Answer (score 0):

1. parent  QCforCC-parent :

   ```
    <artifactId>QCforCC-parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    ...
    ...
    <modules>
        <module>QCforCC-ear</module>
        <module>QCforCC-ejb</module>
        <module>QCforCC-war</module>
    </modules>
   ```
2. QCforCC-ear :

   ```
    <artifactId>QCforCC-ear</artifactId>
    <packaging>ear</packaging>
    ...
    ...
     <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <version>5</version>
          <displayName>XXXXXXXX</displayName>  
          <modules>
             <webModule>             
                <moduleId>WebModule_XXX</moduleId>
                <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                <artifactId>>QCforCC-war</artifactId>   
               <contextRoot>XXXXXXXX</contextRoot>
             </webModule>  
                <jarModule>
                            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
                            <artifactId>QCforCC-ejb</artifactId>
                 </jarModule>            
          </modules>  
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
   ```